# Show oldest to newest of a date range field

Tags: 7, database

I am trying to figure a way to show the oldest to the newest of a date range field that is attached to a taxonomy.

For example: Tax1 (1900-1920), Tax2 (1913-1950), Tax3 (1970-1980)

So how shall I printed like this: (1900-1980)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Split your taxonomy values by (-).

2) Store all the values into an array.

3) Find minimum & maximum value from that array.

Ex:

> $date = array(1900, 1920, 1913, 1950, 1970, 1980);
>
> $result = min($date) . ' - ' . max($date);

Comment: But this to get from fixed values, I want to get values from a field that dynamically changes. Can I use the field name in the $date parameter?

Comment: Dynamically you can do it. I written it for example purpose.
Follow my steps. First try to collect all your dynamic data in an array. Then you can easily proceed further.